# Adding parameters with sqlcommand.parameters.addwithvalue

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sqlcommand

I am not able to get any response from the following code:

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT * FROM users WHERE @parameter LIKE @value", con))
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("parameter", parameter);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("value", value);

    SqlDataReader result = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    return result.HasRows;
}
```

Getting false every time.

Anyone knows why?

Comment: First of all, SQL Server parameter have a leading `@` that you're not supplying. But more importantly - you **cannot** pass a parameter for the column name - if you want to do this, you'll need to use *dynamic SQL* (with all it's shortcomings, warts and pitfalls)

Answer (score 0):

This is  incorrect syntax in SQL

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE @parameter LIKE @value
```

should be something like

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE parameter = @parameter LIKE @value
```

and to add the LIKE parameter do this

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value","%" + value + "%");
```

Answer (score 0):

`cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("parameter", parameter);`

`SqlCommand` will infer that `parameter` is a *string* and so will quote it resulting in:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE 'xxx' LIKE 'yyy'
```

Which is going to be false.

Add the field name via (sanitized) string.format/concatenation.

Comment: thank you for the comment. is there any elegant way to do it?